# Dual of path in a space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there a notion dual to the notion of a path in a topological space? Given that a path in a space $X$ is a continuous function from the interval $[0, 1]$ to X, what would the dual of this notion be, if there is one?

Comment: You mean a path is a continuous map $[0,1] \to X$, yes?

Comment: Oops, yes, that's what I meant. Silly mistake. I'll fix it.

Comment: Perhaps you want Cech-paths? Given an open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of $X$, the Cech-paths are defined to be a collection of open sets $\{O_1, \cdots, O_n\} \subset \mathcal{O}$ such that $O_i \cap O_{i+1} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Perhaps...do you have any references for Cech-paths?

Comment: One could map paths into a chosen abelian group or ring. For example, for a manifold, you could pick a differential form and integrate the path. This is the basic idea of cohomology... but maybe you already know about that?

Comment: For a topological space X, does it make any sense to think of the path space $X^I$ of X as dual to the cylinder object X x I over X?